# Modal doesn't want to show up on the login.php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have this in the start of the page, php checks if password and email are in database and when not shows an error - and the error should be in the modal:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    ?>


    <?php 
    session_start();
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=******', '*****', '******');

    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
        $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
        $user = $statement->fetch();

        //Überprüfung des Passworts
        if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['passwort'])) {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
            header("Location: http://localhost/app/index.php");
        } else {

            $errorMessage = "<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#modal1').modal('show');
            });
            </script>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

And this in the end of the page:

```
 <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>Wrong Password or wrong Email!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I don't understand why wouldn't modal show up cause I run the jquery function after "DOM is ready", which means that it should see materialize.js that is located in the end of the page where modals are described.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks like the script is only in the PHP variable, are you actually echoing the variable to the page?

Comment: Hey, I added echo $errorMessage; but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Where exactly have you added the echo? Also, please define "_it doesn't work_".

Comment: Hey, thanks for comments but I have solved the problem using this method that Hosen in Jast suggested:
`if(location.search === "msg=Login_Failed"){
           //run modal or sweet alert or anything 
       } `
So when let's the password or name is wrong in login form - I redirect the user to the page login.php?msg=Login_Failed and then js script tracks if there is "?msg=Login_Failed" in the url location in browser. If yes, then it opens modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php after submit every form page reload.
and for that you cant show modal.
and after that you fill the `$errorMessage` but dident echo it.
i suggest you to use js for showing modal or better than you can use ajax
if login failed you must redirect a user to login page but with a message in url
like this `login.php?msg=Login_Failed`
and with js you can search for that

```
if(location.search === "msg=Login_Failed"){
           //run modal or sweet alert or anything 
       }
```

OR 
you can use ajax for submit form

```
<script>
var username = document.getelementbyid('username').value;
var password = document.getelementbyid('password').value;
 $.post("your_php_file.php",
  {
    username: username,
    password: password
  },
  function(data){
   if(data == true){
window.location.href = "app/index.php";
}else{
//run modal or anyting here
}
  });
</script>
```